# Tesla radiant energy receiver

Tags: radio, wifi, energy

I'm trying to build the classic-ish radiant energy receiver (as depicted in the picture). I've searched extensively, but everyone just seems to make the circuit with random C values and wire antenna.

My question is...since the circuit picks up wifi, radio,...waves, wouldn't it make sense for it to be in some sort of resonance? I'm pretty sure the C and L values (for the antenna) should be exact if we wanted to draw power from let's say the closest radio station.

Does anyone know how to calculate these values and construct the antenna winding (or should it just be a straight wire pointing up?)
[image: tesla circuit]

Comment: Sure, making the antenna 1/4 or 1/2 of the wavelength you want to receive is mostly a good idea. But don't get your hopes up regarding the amount of energy you will be able to "collect" using this circuit. If you're lucky, a voltemeter will register a DC voltage. **And that will be it**. The power is too low to do anything useful with it. You have to place it very close to a powerful antenna to get reasonable power out of it. WiFi and what else you can find in your home doesn't emit that much power. Which is good for us humans.

Comment: Before you bother building anything read Andy aka's excellent answer to [RF energy harvesting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175121/rf-energy-harvesting).

Comment: As others have mentioned, unless you happen to live next door to your local radio station, or under a broadcast TV antenna, you will not harvest much. It's also illegal in many jurisdictions.

Comment: You might like this old article as a starting point. http://qsl.net/f3wm/sciences/jefimenko.html Metal Christmas garland (even string) as an antenna will gather current from each element, adding to the total collected. An online book https://archive.org/details/TheAmateurScientist has the original articles. Academic but not very useful. Enjoy the adventure.