# GSM vs TV broadcating

Tags: gsm, tv

Is it true that GSM signal's field strength in the atmosphere is dependent on the current number of users whereas for TV and FM broadcating the field strength is usually constant, independent of the number of current subscriber.
I am quite sure of this fact, but could not find some written evidence. Can anyone tell me if I am correct and help me with some written evidence of the same?

Thank you!

Comment: One is a managed network, with quality of service, the other is a one way broadcast service. You can't compare the two.

Comment: @Lior Bilia actually I am talking regarding the RF harvesting

Comment: Have you had a look at the typical received power for each?  People are all "energy harvesting, yo, here we go, free power" but there's really not that much to be had.  Consider that TV receiver sensitivity is rated relative to one milliwatt - and typical received signals are at a tiny fraction of one milliwatt.

Comment: A phone will adjust its transmit power depending on how close it is the the cell centre. The cell tower will tell the phone to do this so it doesn't swamp other users. [Read this Q and A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175121/rf-energy-harvesting) on RF energy harvesting.